# Convert Matrix to lower triangular without using numpy

Tags: python

My code had converted the matrix to lower Triangular Matrix but I need to eliminate the space after the last element in a row. My code is

```
matrix = [
    [2, 9, 9],
    [5, 6, 9],
    [7, 6, 5]
]
n = len(matrix)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if(i<j):
            print("0",end=" ")

        else:
            print(matrix[i][j],end=" ")
    if(i!=n-1):
      print()
```

Outut:

```
Expected Output    Actual Output
2 0 0\n            2 0 0 \n 
5 6 0\n            5 6 0 \n
7 6 5              7 6 5
```

Comment: Why is your expected output *lower* triangular?

Comment: Sorry it is lower triangular matrix

Comment: Please describe what input statements exactly we must use to reproduce your actual output.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your inner loop with an expression that builds the row you want.  You can combine the loop body into a single line, if you like.

```
for i in range(n):
    row = ' '.join(str(matrix[i][j]) if i >= j else "0"
                    for j in range(n))
```

Note that this removes the need for your final `if/print`.

Comment: Did you mean to write a genexp or something? There's no `for` clause inside the `join`.

Comment: Thanks; typing with a half-brain today; didn't test due to lack of proper MCVE set-up.

Comment: I've fixed both and tested the result.

Comment: But here I am getting an error ypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: I have no idea how you're getting an integer 0, since my code doesn't contain that token.  Post the exact code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

n=int(input())
matrix=[]
for k in range(n):
    lst=list(map(int,input().split()))
    matrix.append(lst)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if(i

```
    else:
        if(j==(n-1)):
          print(matrix[i][j],end='')
        else:
          print(matrix[i][j],end=" ")
if(i!=n-1):
  print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input())
matrix=[]
for k in range(n):
    lst=list(map(int,input().split()))
    matrix.append(lst)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if(i<j):
            if(j==(n-1)):
              print("0",end='')
            else:
              print("0",end=" ")

        else:
            if(j==(n-1)):
              print(matrix[i][j],end='')
            else:
              print(matrix[i][j],end=" ")
    if(i!=n-1):
      print()
```